# Set width for the polyline drawn from Gpx in SKmap

Tags: ios, polyline, skmaps, gpx, skobbler-maps

I have drawn the SKGpsElement in the map, and here i would like to customize the polyline drawn for the width, color.

I could only render the color in SKMap 3.0.0 but cannot change the width of the polyline on zooming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the width of the polyline when first creating the polyline, but you cannot change it dynamically (on zoom).